# Subtract a set percentage from a column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I have a small query where code_price is 10% of list price. The problem is that sometimes the code price comes up the same as list price, so I tried this in my query.

```
SELECT round(st_codeprice(ss.stock_no, 'E', 'stockslc')::numeric, 2) as code_price
       ,(select case when code_price = ss.list_price then ss.list_price - (ss.list_price * .10) else code_price end)

from stockslc ss
```

`st_codeprice` is a function that pulls the codeprice from a different database.

The error it is giving me is `ERROR: column "code_price" does not exist` I'm wondering if it is the subtraction that is the problem or the case statement.

Author's note: If I need to change the title, let me know what to change it to, I'm skeptical about this title.

Comment: You do not need the inner `select` - change the query like this: `SELECT round(st_codeprice(ss.stock_no, 'E', 'stockslc')::numeric, 2) as code_price, case when code_price = ss.list_price then ss.list_price - (ss.list_price * .10) else code_price end as disc_price from stockslc ss`

Comment: There are very few database engines that allow you to use a field alias immediately after you declare it.  It appears that postgresql is not one of them.

Comment: `code_price` is an aliased column and cannot be used in the same SELECT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, at time of execution, the code_price alias is unknown. To get around this, you can either do away with the alias completely, or generate it outside of your main SELECT and include it as part of a JOIN (or sub-select)..

Removing the alias would look like this:

```
SELECT round(st_codeprice(ss.stock_no, 'E', 'stockslc')::numeric, 2) as code_price,
(select case when round(st_codeprice(ss.stock_no, 'E', 'stockslc')::numeric, 2) = ss.list_price then ss.list_price - (ss.list_price * .10) else round(st_codeprice(ss.stock_no, 'E', 'stockslc')::numeric, 2) end)
FROM stockslc ss
```

but this is a bit ugly and involves 3 calls to your function per result row.

This is how you would do it with a JOIN:

```
SELECT 
 CASE 
   WHEN code_price = ss.list_price THEN ss.list_price - (ss.list_price * .10) 
   ELSE code_price 
 END
FROM stockslc ss
INNER JOIN (SELECT ss2.stock_no, round(st_codeprice(ss2.stock_no, 'E', 'stockslc')::numeric, 2) as code_price 
            FROM stockslc ss2) res ON ss.stock_no = res.stock_no
```

..which is much cleaner..

Comment: Thank you, just a quick question on it though, the data in the column comes out with three decimal places in some areas, is there a way to round it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this

```
SELECT 

    case when round(st_codeprice(ss.stock_no, 'E', 'stockslc')::numeric, 2) = ss.list_price 
        then ss.list_price - (ss.list_price * .10) 
        else round(st_codeprice(ss.stock_no, 'E', 'stockslc')::numeric, 2)
    end as code_price

from stockslc ss
```